# Notepad++ and XML - Replace and capitalize the first letter of all words in a tag element

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, xml, multiple-instances

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<id>1</id>
<name>alligator and stingray</name>
...
<id>99999</id>
<name>dolphin with carp</name>
```

I need result:

```
<id>1</id>
<name>Alligator And Stingray</name>
...
<id>99999</id>
<name>Dolphin With Carp</name>
```

I used this regex:

```
 Search: (<name>)(.*)(</name>)
 Replace: \1\u\2\3
```

The results I received:

```
<id>1</id>
<name>Alligator and stingray</name>
...
<id>99999</id>
<name>dolphin with carp</name>
```

It only capitalizes on the first word of the first ID, and the remaining words and words on other IDs remain unchanged (still lowercase)!

I was doing something wrong?

Help appreciated - Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the structure of the file, this might not be possible. Freddy's answer is not context-aware, so it would match every word regardless of what tag it is in. You should consider using a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<name>|\G)\K\b(\w)(\w+\s*)`
- Replace with: `\u$1$2`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:<name>|\G)   # non capture group, "<name>" or restart from previous match position
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\b              # word boundary
(\w)            # group 1, 1 word character
(\w+\s*)        # group 2, 1 or more word characters followed by optional space
```

**Replacement:**

```
\u$1        # uppercase content of group 1 (i.e. the first letter)
$2          # content of group 2 (i.e. the rest of the word)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<id>1</id>
<name>Alligator And Stingray</name>
...
<id>99999</id>
<name>Dolphin With Carp</name>
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Your answer also encountered a non-capitalization of the same unicode characters of @Freddy above!
But I appreciate it because it overcomes fix "block overflow" (it capitalization text in `<name>` only)  for the answer of @Freddy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   Find what: ([>\s])([a-z])
Replace with: \1\u\2
```

This changes a lower case character to upper case if the previous character is a space character or `>`.

Comment: It didn't capitalize unicode letters (eg, ă, â, đ, ê, ...) and it also capitalized the words of other tags not only <name> (I just hope it capitalized for unique tag <name> and other tags aren't needed).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Use @Toto's answer. This one does not use non-regular language features and can, therefore, never answer the question completely, although it does solve the finite length cases (now).

---

What you are trying to do is only possible if there is a maximum number of words in a `<name>...</name>` block.

The problem with your current regex is that group \2 applies to the whole of the text inside the tags (`alligator and stingray`) in your example and \u operates only on the character immediately following it.

If there is a maximum number of words in a node, you may use a regex similar to this one:

Find what: `<name>(\w)(\w* ?)(\w?)(\w*? ?)(\w?)(\w*? ?)</name>`
Replace with: `<name>\U\1\E\2\U\3\E\4\U\5\E\6</name>`

If you don't know how many words are in one node, you should use an XML Parser instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to capitalize the first letter of all the words in the `<name>...</name>` block, and it hasn't same length between ids, will have ids with long words, and vice versa.